# Clustering data with dates by hour, day, week, month, year objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I have a Stat object that has properties time and count. I have a (sorted by time) list of these objects that are coming in every hour. I'd like to cluster for display. 
Is there a nice way to cluster data by time in objective c? or a nicer algorithm than the naive one below?

It's an example of doing it weekly. Others are similar but you change out the date components.

```
-(void) makeWeeklyData{

    Stat *prev = self.hourlyData[0];
    NSInteger sum = 0;
    NSMutableArray *weeklyData = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (CSInstallStat *data in self.hourlyData) {
        NSDateComponents *itemComps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:data.time];
        [itemComps setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];

        NSDateComponents *currComps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:kCFCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:prev.time];
        [currComps setCalendar:[NSCalendar currentCalendar]];

        if ([itemComps weekOfYear] == [currComps weekOfYear] && [itemComps month] == [currComps month] && [itemComps year] == [currComps year])  {//Same Week
            sum += data.count;
        } else if([itemComps weekOfYear] >= [currComps weekOfYear] && [itemComps month] == [currComps month] && [itemComps year] == [currComps year]) { //Next Week

            Stat *stat = [[CSInstallStat alloc] init];
            stat.time = [currComps date];
            stat.count = sum;
            stat.timeAccuracy  = ENUMWeekly;
            [weeklyData addObject:stat];
            sum = 0;
            sum += data.count;
            prev = data;
        } else {
            prev = data;
        }

    }
    self.weeklyData = weeklyData;


}
```

Comment: My [MBCalendarKit](http://github.com/mosheberman/MBCalendarKit) library contains some categories on NSCalendar and NSDate that you might find useful.

Answer (score 0):

If I was implementing this kind of system, I’d be inclined to maintain the statistics as the objects come in.  So, let’s say we have an array of “weekly data”, and let’s say for sake of argument that we want to keep 52 weeks worth of it.  In your class, declare member variables:

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar;
unsigned    lastItemWeek;
struct weekinfo {
  unsigned frequency;
  unsigned month;
  int year;
} weeklyStats[53];
```

When a new value comes in, you just do

```
- (id)init
{
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    ...
    /* Must fix the calendar we're using, or at least understand the one we're
       using.  Using [NSCalendar currentCalendar] is potentially risky as we
       don't necessarily know what that is. */
    gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    ...
  }
}

- (void)gotNewItemWithDate:(NSDate *)date
{
  NSDateComponents *itemComps = [gregorianCalendar
                                 components:(NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit
                                             | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear)
                                 fromDate:date];
  unsigned week = [itemComps week] - 1; // This runs from 0 to 52 inclusive
  unsigned month = [itemComps month];
  int year = [itemComps year];

  if (week == lastItemWeek)
    ++weeklyStats[week].frequency;
  else {
    // Some years don't have week 53 (which we store in weeklyStats[52])
    if (week == 0 && lastItemWeek == 51)
      weeklyStats[52] = (struct weekinfo){ 0, 0, 0 };

    weeklyStats[week] = (struct weekinfo){ 1, month, year };
  }
  lastItemWeek = week;
}
```

You could store that in `Stat` objects instead if you really want, but that seems a little unnecessary.

It should also be obvious that you can extend this approach to maintain daily statistics and so on.

Two caveats:

1. Weeks are tricky; some years have 53 weeks, some have 52.  As a result, `weeklyStats[52]` may or may not be valid.  I’ve chosen here to clear it when we get to week 0 if we were last at week 52.
2. The element given by `weeklyStats[lastItemWeek]` is not a final value.

Comment: You're hard coding year lengths in weeks - that's going to break for some calendar systems.

Comment: @Moshe Yes. That’s why the code also hard codes the calendar, and it’s why there’s a great big comment about it in the code above. This is, of course, only a problem if the OP was expecting to use the user’s localised calendar rather than the Gregorian calendar (doubtful IMO).

Comment: You'd be very surprised about that kind of thing. Apple encourages localization.

Comment: @Moshe I’m well aware that localisation is encouraged, thank-you very much (I’ve been coding for Apple systems since 2000).  However, if I’m right about the OP’s intent, he just wants to have a weekly statistic available.  It doesn’t actually matter how many weeks are in a year to do that; what matters is that there is a continuous stream of data at the output.  Explicitly using the Gregorian calendar to get week numbers is a convenient way to achieve that.